# How can I read excel data (office 2007 xlsx) in PHP?

Tags: php

How can I read excel data (office 2007 xlsx) in PHP?
Is there any library for this?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606523/handling-office-open-xml-xlsx-documents-with-php

Comment: PHPExcel is the first result on google with keywords "php excel 2007" and seems to do the job.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[PHPExcel](http://www.codeplex.com/PHPExcel), it is a really good utility!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use PHPExcel, here is something to [get you started](http://www.oshuamoreno.com/2009/10/phpexcel-read-excel-from-lamp/)

The only other resources I am using at the moment are its documentation. Not much info on the web.

Answer (score 0):

What about http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/ ?